# Automate Process Documentation for Boomi

Tags: documentation-generation, boomi

I've inherited dozens of integrations that were built by someone else.  Are there any tools that will automate documenting the process flow and actions the boomi integration is taking?

In the new world of AI, not sure is this is feasible yet or not.